# how do I simulate a PENDING response from the paypal IPN for testing purposes?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I need to simulate a PENDING response to my IPN script (php).

Any help on how to configure the sandbox seller account in order to do this would be great!

Note that the IPN testing tool is not sufficient, I actually just need to it to send back a 'pending' notification.

Apologies if this is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn on 'Payment review' on your Sandbox seller account via https://developer.paypal.com/
This will put any new transactions going through this test account in a 'Pending' state.

1. https://developer.paypal.com/
2. Test Accounts
3. Payment Review > Click 'Disabled'

[image: PayPal Developer Central with Payment Review available]

Comment: this sounds great - but I can't find the setting anywhere!! paypal docs seem to say it's in the test accounts page at developer.paypal.com, but it's not! i've been through all the profile links to no avail! Please help! :)

Comment: It's not the Profile links of the Sandbox account itself, it's within https://developer.paypal.com, as the doc states. I've added a screenshot above. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if PayPal had this back when the question was asked but their IPN simulator is very convenient for testing pending responses and other responses.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator