# PayPal Sandbox test seller always "completed / instant" - I want to test pending

Tags: api, paypal, sandbox, paypal-sandbox

I successfully tested PayPal payments (express checkout) with status "completed" ("instant"). However, I would like to test pending payments. I already set "Review Payments" to "On" (see [how do I simulate a PENDING response from the paypal IPN for testing purposes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975700/how-do-i-simulate-a-pending-response-from-the-paypal-ipn-for-testing-purposes)) for the sandbox buyer account, but it still gives me payment status "Completed" and "instant" instead of "pending". Apparently, the new PayPal Developer environment seems to make problems ([Negative testing on paypal sandbox no more available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276622/negative-testing-on-paypal-sandbox-no-more-available))

I would like to test the scenario when a customer pays with an eCheck ("Lastschriftverfahren" in Germany).

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Negative Test Mode and Payment Review are two separate features.

Payment Review does work. I was able to test it properly. You said you enabled Payment Review on the Buyer account and that would be the cause of the problem. Payment Review needs to be added to the account that receives the payment.

Payment Review sets incoming transactions to all be "Under Review" so they have to be approved manually be the receiver.

Comment: Is it possible to simulate the payment being approved after it is "under review" (ie: changing from state "pending" to state "completed") in the sandbox?